# Attempt to generate email with new lines from Python through Bash mailx command

Tags: python, linux

Where I work, we have servers that are pre-configured for the use of the bash mail command to send attachments and messages. I'm working on a notification script that will monitor server activity and generate an email if it detects an issue. I'm using the subprocess.call function in order to send a bash command.

I am successful in sending messages, but in the body portion of the email, it is stringing each notification line together rather than putting each notification on a separate line. I have tried to append each line within the string with "\n" and "\r\n". I have to use double backslashes as python will interpret this as literal new lines when it sends the echo command. I also passed the command "shopt -s xpg_echo" before using the echo with pipe to mail using the double backspaces but this also had no effect. I also tried using echo without the "-e" option and this had no effect either.

The trick is that I need python to send the new line to bash and then somehow get bash to interpret this as a new line using echo piped through to mail. Here is a sample of the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time
import re
import subprocess
import smtplib

serviceports["SCP Test"] = ["22"]
serviceports["Webtier"] = ["9282"]

bashCommand = "netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v LISTENING"
netstat_results = subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
netstat_results = str(netstat_results)

#Iterate through all ports for each service and assign down ports to variable

for servicename, ports in serviceports.items():
  for ind_port in ports:
    ind_port_chk = ":" + ind_port
    count = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(ind_port_chk), netstat_results))
    if count == 0:
      warning = servicename + " on port " + ind_port + " is currently down!"
      report.append(warning)

for warning in report:
  message = message + warning + "\\\n"

fromaddr=serveridsimp + "@xxxxx.com"
toaddr='email@xxxxx.com'
subject="Testing..."
body=message
cmd= cmd='echo -e '+body+' | mail -s '+subject+' -r '+fromaddr+' '+toaddr
send=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

The code runs a netstat command and assigns it to a string. The code will then iterate through the specified ports and search for where that port doesn't exist in the netstat string (netstat_results). It then will create a list object (warning) containing all the ports not located in netstat_results and then append each line adding \n to a string called "message". It then sends an echo piped to the xmail command to generate an email to be sent containing all the ports not found. What happens currently is that I will get an email saying something like this:
SCP Test on port 22 is currently down!nOHS Webtier on port 9282 is currently down!n etc...

I want it to put each message on a new line like so:

- SCP Test on port 22 is currently down!
- Webtier on port 9282 is currently down!

I am trying to avoid writing the output to a file and then using bash to read it back into the mail command. Is this possible without having to create a file?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue by changing the command sent to bash and character being appended to the following:

```
    message = message + warning + "\n"

cmd= cmd='echo -e '+'"'+body+'"'+'|awk \'{ print $0"   " }\''+' | mail -s '+'"'+subject+'"'+' -r '+fromaddr+' '+toaddr
```